# Retrieve output parameter of SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, output-parameter

I'm using a table with two columns, `customer_id` and `customer_name`.

`customer_name` is a simple `varchar`, `customer_id` is an auto incrementing primary key.

I want to use my C# application to insert a `customer_name`, and retrieve the value of the `customer_id`.

Just inserting is simply solved by using

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(AppConstants.ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO custom_customer (customer_name) VALUES (@name);"))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("name", customer));
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I found some documentation of the `OUTPUT` statement, which can be used to retrieve a value.

I think the correct syntax would be

```
INSERT INTO custom_customer (customer_name) 
OUTPUT Inserted.customer_id 
VALUES (@name);
```

And I figure I need to use

```
command.ExecuteReader();
```

But then I'm stuck. How should I go about getting the value from the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use the `ExecuteNonQuery` to write operations. After execute command, you can read the parameter from `Parameters` collection, since you have set the parameter as a output parameter, for sample:

```
command.Parameters["name"].Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

object name = command.Parameters["name"].Value;
```

If you want to know what `Id` the identity column generated after the insert, you could use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` sql command, and use the `ExecuteScalar()` to get the result of command, for sample:

```
int id;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(AppConstants.ConnectionString))
{
    string sql = @"INSERT INTO custom_customer (customer_name) 
                                        VALUES (@name); 
                   SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("name", customer));
        connection.Open();
        id = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to return inserted id and not the same value he is passing as paramter

Comment: The second answer here was very helpful, just one thing for future readers: replace SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() with SELECT CONVERT(int, SCOPE_IDENTITY()).      

Casting the return value of simply SCOPE_IDENTITY() into an int yields a format exception, since the standard return value is 
numeric(38,0), which is unhandled.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ExecuteScalar`  instead

```
int id = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `ExecuteScalar()` to get the `ID` value:

```
int ID= (int) Command.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(AppConstants.ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO custom_customer (customer_name) VALUES (@name);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"))
{
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("name", customer));
    connection.Open();
    int id= (int)Command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```